# hashmap with key of custom class type

Tags: java

I have class

```
public class server_run{
    class constatnt_Cells{
            private int x;
            private int y;
            public constatnt_Cells(int fx , int fy) {
                x = fx;
                y = fy;
            }
        }
    private static  Map <constatnt_Cells,Integer> test = new HashMap<constatnt_Cells,Integer>();
}
```

And I want to create `hashmap` which `constatnt_Cells` as key and `Integer` as Value but here is the problem that static part dose't work in this case
I explain my problem with an example

```
    constatnt_Cells goldCell = new constatnt_Cells(2,6);
    System.out.println(test.get(goldCell));
    test.put(goldCell, 50);
```

This code always print **null** but if I change the type of key of `hashmap` to for example integer

```
System.out.println(test.get(10));
test.put(10, 50);
```

It only print **null** once and after that it always print **50** so what is the difference between `constatnt_Cells` class and `Integer` class in this case.
All of my code is in `server_run` class and like it's name server run this class each second

Comment: Why are you using `get()` before `put()`?

Comment: because I want to see that my static hashmap work or not if it work just in the first second it print null and the other time it should print 50

Comment: You need to override equals and hashcode methods. Unless you do this, all instances created shall be different first of all.

Comment: Sorry but I am not a java professional would you explain your answer?

Comment: If you use the default `hashcode` function and do not override `equals` method. I think your code should works fine. Pls provide your implementation of `hashcode` and `equals` if any.

Comment: @VicX how the map will verify key if that exists already or not ?

Comment: @Daniel.V: Read here - http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20. hashcode and equals method overriding is required in case you are using a custom class as key in map.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjewP3dwcvJAhWBao4KHQOiB6wQFgg1MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2265503%2Fwhy-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java&usg=AFQjCNHXl9GjCtkfdI7hkm8KXMStE42lCQ&sig2=KiUoKC8f2CkprNBO6fgRGQ&bvm=bv.109332125,d.c2E

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the comment section can not post so many code, I post an answer here.
The following is the source code of HashMap.get(o:Obejct) function in java 8:

```
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    Entry<K,V> entry = getEntry(key);

    return null == entry ? null : entry.getValue();
}
```

And

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can see, when you want to get an object from a HashMap, it will first compute the hash code of the `key`  and find the entry in the inner hash table that has the same hash code. Then the method will test if the key and the `key of the entry in hash table` are **equal** by test if they point to the same reference by `==` operator or are they equal by invoke the `equals` method that your class override.

The following is the `hash` method

```
final int hash(Object k) {
    int h = hashSeed;
    if (0 != h && k instanceof String) {
        return sun.misc.Hashing.stringHash32((String) k);
    }

    h ^= k.hashCode();

    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

**So, pleas pay enough attention to your `hashcode` and `equals` functions to your class when you want your instances work as expected  with `HashMap`**

Comment: how equality shall be checked ? Do you know how  `key.equals(k) will work here.`

Comment: @SacJn As I said in my post it will call the `equals` method if you have override the `equals` method or it will call the `equals` method in class Object which by default is just to test the references by `==`

Comment: But the question of the hour is shouldn't he override the equals and hashcode ? What ever you have written will not make sense to OP's problem.

Comment: @SacJn I'm just answering your question in the comment.You have pointed that all the instances by default are different, you are right but in this question, there's is only one instance. So I said if he use the default `hashcode` function it should works. So I ask him to provided his implementation of `hashcode` and `equals`. I think I should delete my post as you said.

Comment: There also I just asked you how will it check equality of two custom class instances. You need minimum 2 instances to check if this code is working fine or not.

Comment: You are right. But in this case since there is only one instance, it will not even call `key.equals(k)` since it will pass the `(k = e.key) == key` test if the author use default hashcode function.